# Strange Dependency Issue With Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

***UPDATE:*** *I gave it a couple of days, with no answers, so I will be starting to modify the repos, in an effort to fix the problem (I'll get it, eventually).*

I am absolutely sure that "I'm not holding it right," but there's no way for me to diagnose the issue.

[I have also made a similar post on the Swift Forums.](https://forums.swift.org/t/having-very-strange-package-manager-dependency-chain-issues/37853)

I have [this package](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox), which is consumed by [this package](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_BlueThoth), which is, in turn, consumed by [this app](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/BlueVanClef). [The first package](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox) is also consumed by [this package](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_PersistentPrefs), which is also consumed by [the app](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/BlueVanClef). That chain works fine, but is also a great deal simpler.

The issue is that I get an error inside [the RVS_BlueThoth package](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_BlueThoth) during [the BlueVanClef](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/BlueVanClef) build.

The error is consistent with [the RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox) package not building in [the RVS_BlueThoth package](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_BlueThoth) build (the module is not available), but I can't figure out why. There is nothing but a blank serialized diagnostics file for one of the files that consumes [the RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox) module, and no other errors, other than the file isn't there.

If I build [the RVS_BlueThoth package](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_BlueThoth) independently, I have no issues, but including it in [the BlueVanClef app](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/BlueVanClef) consistently reports this error.

Like I said, I am sure that the problem is mine. I just can't figure out how to get to it.

Thanks for any help!

(For example, is there any diagnostic utility available for SPM?)

Here's a diagram of the dependencies:

[image: A diagram of the Package Hierarchy]

Note the dotted line between RVS_BlueThoth and RVS_Persistent_Prefs. That's because the dependency is only for test harnesses, and is not used by Blue Van Clef.

Here are the various Package.swift Files:

[RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox/blob/master/Package.swift):

```
// swift-tools-version:5.2

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v11),
        .tvOS(.v11),
        .macOS(.v10_14),
        .watchOS(.v5)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "RVS-Generic-Swift-Toolbox",
            type: .dynamic,
            targets: ["RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox"])
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox",
            path: "./src")
    ]
)
```

[RVS_Persistent_Prefs](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_PersistentPrefs/blob/master/Package.swift) (This one works):

```
// swift-tools-version:5.2
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "RVS_Persistent_Prefs",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v11),
        .tvOS(.v11),
        .macOS(.v10_14),
        .watchOS(.v5)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "RVS-Persistent-Prefs",
            type: .dynamic,
            targets: ["RVS_Persistent_Prefs"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(
            url: "git@github.com:RiftValleySoftware/RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox.git",
            from: "1.2.1"
        )
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "RVS_Persistent_Prefs",
            path: "./src")
    ]
)
```

[RVS_BlueThoth](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_BlueThoth/blob/master/Package.swift) (This one does not work):

```
// swift-tools-version:5.2
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "RVS_BlueThoth",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v11),
        .tvOS(.v11),
        .macOS(.v10_14),
        .watchOS(.v5)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "RVS-BlueThoth",
            type: .dynamic,
            targets: ["RVS_BlueThoth"]
        )
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(
            url: "git@github.com:RiftValleySoftware/RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox.git",
            from: "1.2.1"
        ),
        .package(
            url: "git@github.com:RiftValleySoftware/RVS_PersistentPrefs.git",
            from: "1.1.1"
        )
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "RVS_BlueThoth",
            path: "./src/Source"
        )
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Solved. Finally.

I was, indeed, "holding it wrong," but it was not easy to tell.

The best way to debug was to `cd` to the package directory, and do a `swift build`. That helped me to see the errors as they happened (They were not reflected in the Xcode logs).

The issue was that I needed to do the dependency in **TWO** places. I had it only in one. Now that I look back on it, it was a fairly natural structure, but was complicated by the fact that I needed to rename the product of the dependency to use dashes, instead of underscores.

This was fixed by changing the RVS_BlueThoth Package.swift file to like so:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.2

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "RVS_BlueThoth",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v11),
        .tvOS(.v11),
        .macOS(.v10_14),
        .watchOS(.v5)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(name: "RVS-BlueThoth", type: .dynamic, targets: ["RVS_BlueThoth"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox", url: "git@github.com:RiftValleySoftware/RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox.git", from: "1.2.1")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "RVS_BlueThoth",
            dependencies: [.product(name: "RVS-Generic-Swift-Toolbox", package: "RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox")],
            path: "./src/Source"
        )
    ]
)
```

The money shot was this line:

`dependencies: [.product(name: "RVS-Generic-Swift-Toolbox", package: "RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox")]`

Note that the `name` argument is `"RVS-Generic-Swift-Toolbox"`, NOT `"RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox"`, but the package name had the underscores (I probably could do without the `name` argument in the global dependency list).

That is because [I had to swap underscores for dashes in order to get the app to be accepted by the App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62477747/swift-package-manager-problem-with-bundle-ids).

I was also able to simplify the dependency chain a bit, because some dependencies were only required for test harnesses.

***UPDATE:*** *I wanted to mention that the thing that made it for me, was the error response from the `swift build` command. It was awesome. It actually had the code that I needed to use. It was that response that showed me that I need to use dashes, mixed with underscores. That was not something that I was understanding.*